# Help understanding the $1$-form $d\theta$ where $\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, angle

$\newcommand{\atan}{\operatorname{atan2}}$On the [one-form page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form) (and other sources), the *change in angle formula* $\theta=\atan(y,x)$ (defined up to an additive constant) leads to the total derivative:
$$
d\theta = -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy.
$$

This derivative is continuously defined except at the origin. Integrating this quantity over a closed loop gives winding number times $2\pi$.

1. Now, I have some arbitrary function $f(\theta)$ from physics that I want to integrate over a closed loop. I can perform the integral $\oint f(\theta) \, d\theta$ with no issue. Am I right in saying that I can rewrite this integration in terms of $x,y$ as follows:

$$
\oint f(\theta) \, d\theta = \oint \left[-f(\atan(y,x))\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx + f(\atan(y,x))\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy\right] \text{?}
$$

2. Now, the arbitrary function $f(\theta)$ above happens contain $\theta$ derivatives of a function $g(\theta)$:
   $$f(\theta)=\frac d {d\theta} g(\theta)+\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2} g(\theta).$$
   How do I rewrite the derivative in terms of derivatives of $x,y$? I think, by the chain rule, it should be:
   $$
   \frac d {d\theta} = \frac\partial {\partial x} \frac{dx}{d\theta} + \frac\partial{\partial y}\frac{dx}{d\theta}.
   $$

**But is there no way to write this without having the $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ and $\frac{dy}{d\theta}$ terms directly?** At least in terms of different notation? For instance, I was thinking that I could define a 'unit tangent vector' along the loop and allow it to contain these derivatives/speeds.

3. Can I write a proper 2-form using the 1-form product $f(\theta) \, d\theta$, only in terms of $x,y$? I was thinking I could do:
   $$
   \frac d {dx} \left[f(\atan(y,x))\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right] - \frac d {dy} \left[-f(\atan(y,x))\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right] \, dx \wedge dy,
   $$

but I am not sure about this.
Since I want to understand this in broad generality, I want to do this without using specific examples of $f,g$. Thank you.